# Create columns that extract and flag a detected string pattern from multiple selected columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, across

I have the below dataframe, where each observation has a string of key and values (*k:v*)s of different objects. Each object is separated by a `\n`

```r
df = tribble(
  ~col, ~summary,
  "a",   "Oranges: 1\nApples: 1\nPeaches: 6\nBananas: 2",
  "b",   "Apples: 2\nBananas: 1",
  "c",   "Oranges: 4\nPeaches: 2\nBananas: 5",
  "d",   "Peaches: 2"
)
```

I have separated those values as below:

```r
df_sep = df %>% 
  separate(summary,c("col1","col2","col3","col4"),sep = "\n")
```

I would like to have the below output using **dplyr** possibly with `across` and `any` if applciable.

```
# A tibble: 4 x 10
  col   summary                                       Apples_flag Bananas_flag oranges_flag Peaches_flag_value Apples_value Bananas_value oranges_value Peaches_value
  <chr> <chr>                                               <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>              <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 b     Apples: 2, Bananas: 1                                   1            1            0                  0            2             1             0             0
2 a     Oranges: 1, Apples: 1, Peaches: 6, Bananas: 2           1            1            1                  1            1             2             1             6
3 c     Oranges: 4, Peaches: 2, Bananas: 5                      0            1            1                  1            0             5             4             2
4 d     Peaches: 2                                              0            0            0                  1            0             0             0             2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way would be:

```
df %>%
  left_join(df%>%
  separate_rows(summary, sep='\n') %>%
  separate(summary, c('name', 'value'), convert = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(col,names_glue = '{name}_value', values_fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(across(-col, sign, .names = '{.col}_flag')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility within the `tidyverse` which relies on pivoting the data:

```
df %>% 
  separate(summary,c("col1","col2","col3","col4"),sep = "\n", fill = "right") %>%
  gather(dummy, value, -col) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  group_by(col) %>%
  transmute(
    col,
    summary = paste(value, collapse = ", "),
    fruit = gsub(": \\d+", "", value),
    n = parse_number(value)
  ) %>%
  arrange(fruit) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = fruit, values_from = n, values_fill =  0) %>%
  mutate(across(-summary, list(flag = sign)))


# A tibble: 4 x 10
# Groups:   col [4]
  col   summary                                       Apples Bananas oranges Peaches Apples_flag Bananas_flag oranges_flag Peaches_flag
  <chr> <chr>                                          <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 b     Apples: 2, Bananas: 1                              2       1       0       0           1            1            0            0
2 a     oranges: 1, Apples: 1, Peaches: 6, Bananas: 2      1       2       1       6           1            1            1            1
3 c     oranges: 4, Peaches: 2, Bananas: 5                 0       5       4       2           0            1            1            1
4 d     Peaches: 2                                         0       0       0       2           0            0            0            1
```

Comment: Appreciate the solution but I couldn't trace and imagine the actions chronologically in my head while inspecting the code. I have posted a simple solution that I can trace its steps from the code. Feel free to suggest any improvements to it.

Answer (score 0):

The below is another possible solution within the `tidyverse` utilizing `c_cross`, `any`, `str_detect` and `str_match`.

It does the flagging by applying `str_detect` to `any` of the specified columns from the `match` argument and adding 1 as a flag using `+` to the appropriate column.

It extracts the value by applying a regex using `str_match` and adds it to the appropriate column.

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(summary_clone = summary) %>% 
  separate(summary_clone,c("col1","col2","col3","col4"),sep = "\n", fill = "right") %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
# Flagging
  mutate(Apples_flag = +any(str_detect(c_across(matches("col[1-4]")), "Apples")),
         Oranges_flag = +any(str_detect(c_across(matches("col[1-4]")), "oranges")),
         Bananas_flag = +any(str_detect(c_across(matches("col[1-4]")), "Bananas")),
         Peaches_flag = +any(str_detect(c_across(matches("col[1-4]")), "Peaches"))
         ) %>% 
  mutate(summary = str_replace_all(summary,"\\n"," ")) %>% 
# Parse matched values
  mutate(Apples_value =  str_match(summary,"Apples: (\\d+)")[2],
         Oranges_value =  str_match(summary,"Oranges: (\\d+)")[2],
         Bananas_value =  str_match(summary,"Bananas: (\\d+)")[2],
         Peaches_value =  str_match(summary,"Peaches: (\\d+)")[2]
         )  %>% 
  select(-matches("col[1-4]")) %>% 
  mutate(across(3:10, .fns = ~replace_na(as.numeric(.),0))) 

# A tibble: 4 x 10
# Rowwise: 
 col   summary                                    Apples_flag Oranges_flag Bananas_flag Peaches_flag Apples_value Oranges_value Bananas_value Peaches_value
 <chr> <chr>                                            <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 a     Oranges: 1 Apples: 1 Peaches: 6 Bananas: 2           1            1            1            1            1             0             2             6
2 b     Apples: 2 Bananas: 1                                 1            0            1            0            2             0             1             0
3 c     Oranges: 4 Peaches: 2 Bananas: 5                     0            1            1            1            0             0             5             2
4 d     Peaches: 2                                           0            0            0            0            0             0             0             0
```

Comment: The weakness of this solution is that for each fruit you have to use mutate twice. This becomes infeasible if you have say 40 different types of fruit instead of 4.

Comment: Yes, it is also slower due to the `rowwie()` operation.